# how to validate date field in jquery addmethod

Tags: jquery

I need to validate the entered date in the text box using jquery in `addmethod`. The date not be more than the date which is 1 year from current date and also to be in format `dd/mm/YYYY`.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanToday", function(value, element) { 
var now=new Date(); 
if ( !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value)) ) { 
return new Date(value) > now; 
} 
return isNaN(value) || (parseFloat(value) > now); }, "* The date should not be greater than today.");
```

Comment: I have tried with the given code : jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanToday", function(value, element) {
     var now=new Date(); 
     if ( !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value)) ) { 
        return new Date(value) > now; 
     } 
     return isNaN(value) || (parseFloat(value) > now); 
  }, "* The date should not be greater than today.");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanToday",function(value) {
        var isValid = value.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/);
        if(isValid){
            var datetime = value;
            var date = new Date();
            var parts = datetime.split('/');
            var day = parseInt(parts[0]);
            var month = parseInt(parts[1])-1;
            var year = parseInt(parts[2]);
            var maxyear = date.getFullYear()+1;
            var maxDay = date.getDate();
            var maxMonth = date.getMonth();
            var enteredDate = new Date(year, month, day);
            var maxDate = new Date(maxyear, maxMonth, maxDay);
            if (enteredDate <= maxDate) {
              isValid = true;
            }
            else{
              isValid =  false;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }, "Not a valid date");

$("#date").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        return false; 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="date" action="#" method="">
    <div>
        <label for="datetime">dd/mm/yyyy<input type="text" name="datetime" id="checkDate" value="23/05/2017" class="required greaterThanToday"/></label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Check" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks amal got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( { minDate: -0, maxDate: new Date(2018, 5,22) });
```

if you want to used static date then used `new date(2018,5,22)`
and if you want dynamic date then used `+1 year`.

i think it will be usefull for you

Comment: Ya thanks for the ans. But here i havent used any date picker. I have used only the text box. also can u pls give the ans in addmethod